# ListView by extending Fragment instead of ListFragment

Tags: android, list, listview, android-fragments

I currently have a fragment which extends ListFragment and I just place that in the onCreate of the fragment :

```
....
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( mData );
setListAdapter(adapter);
....
```

and it works just great, I have a list of what I need.

The thing is , I want to add a button (for now ImageButton , later on floating action button) so it will always be visible at the bottom-right of this fragment. 
If I add the button to the list_item layout it will just place the button on each item list . How do I separate them ?
I've only found examples for doing so with activities,not fragments.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a custom layout for your fragment (not the list item layout), in which you can put your button or whatever you want. And don't forget to inflate your new layout in `onCreate()` method: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourNewLayout, container, false); return view;`

Comment: @Rami the yourNewLayout will be consisted of a FrameLayout that will hold ListView and ImageButton ?

Comment: You can use a RelativeLayout as aprent, where you put your ListView and above of it the ImageButton.

Comment: Ok but I'm a bit confused. The lines you said to place in onCreate include "return view;".
 onCreate is void, it doesn't return anything. Did I misunderstand you?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry i mean onCreateView() not onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onCreateView()` method like that:

```
    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_layout, container, false);
          ....
          MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( mData );
          setListAdapter(adapter);
          ....

          return view;
      }
```

Your `list_fragment_layout.mxl` should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Rami. 
So basically I shouldn't do anything in onCreate except for some data initializing I'd need. And then the onCreateView will look like something that you wrote here , and I can add there in-between 
`ImageView myButton=(ImageView) findByViewId( R.id.myImageView);
myButton.setOnClickListener(....);`
Right?

Comment: just last question
How do I modify the ListView in XML ? so it will have a certain layout of widgets

Comment: No, the button will be displayed only above the ListView (the whole list, not in each row). What do you mean by "how do I modify the ListView in XML ? so it will have a certain layout of widgets"?

Comment: well earlier  I defined a layout of each item ,which consists of checkbox, and two textviews. so basically I can control each widget in the item. How is it done now ?

Comment: You don't need to change anything, here we just create a custom xml file for the Fragment (that contains ListView+imageView) instead of using the default one that contains only a ListView. Your CheckBox and TextView control must be done in your Adapter, we haven't touch the adapter code so there is no impact to your widgets control.

Comment: oh I got it! 
Thank you again !